# How to remove the "fuzzy" drop shadow in the UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I don't want the drop shadow when the UIPopoverController's view appears. Is there a way to remove this drop shadow look?

Answer (score 12):

Not straight forward, but since iOS 5, you can make your own custom popover background using UIPopoverBackgroundView.

See the answer for this question: [Using UIPopoverBackgroundView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205846/using-uipopoverbackgroundview-class). It's pointing to a good tuto.

Then, in the initWithFrame of your UIPopoverBackgroundView implementation, you can use a clearColor for the drop shadow. Using offset and radius did not work for me.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. As long as your stuff looks good and behaves properly, it will make it through review.

Answer (score 0):

The shadow is an attribute of the popover view's layer. If you could get access to the layer, you could set it's shadow radius to 0.0 and shadow offset to {0.0, 0.0}. However, it looks like the view must be a private ivar of the popover controller, so there's not an easy way to get to it. Moreover, if you're looking to distribute this app through the app store, using a private ivar and changing the look of standard UI elements both are likely to get your app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use your custom UIPopoverBackgroundView and there implement this function:

```
+ (BOOL)wantsDefaultContentAppearance {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Does not get called;