# Using UIPopoverBackgroundView class

Tags: ios, ios5, uipopoverbackgroundview

Apple is missing documentation on how to use `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class introduced in iOS5. Anyone have an example?

I have tried to subclass it, but my XCode 4.2 on Lion is missing `UIPopoverBackgroundView.h`

***Edit:*** Unsurprisingly, it should have been imported as `#import <UIKit/UIPopoverBackgroundView.h>`

Comment: Are you sure you couldn't find the documentation?: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: CodaFI already answered about documentation...other subject is this example, http://blog.brandoncopley.com/?p=72 good luck

Comment: Maybe looking in the wrong SDK?

Comment: Thanks for #import <UIKit/UIPopoverBackgroundView.h>  :)

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](http://blog.andrewkolesnikov.com/custom-background-color-tint-for-uipopover-64835)

Answer (score 15):

To add to the other, link-only answers, here is how this is done.

- Create a new subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView
- Declare the following in your interface:

  ```
  +(UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets;
  +(CGFloat)arrowHeight;
  +(CGFloat)arrowBase;

  @property(nonatomic,readwrite) CGFloat arrowOffset;
  @property(nonatomic,readwrite) UIPopoverArrowDirection arrowDirection;
  ```
- The class methods are straightforward: `contentViewInsets` returns the width of your borders all the way round (not including the arrow), `arrowHeight` is the height of your arrow, `arrowBase` is the base of your arrow.
- Implement the two property setters, **making sure to call `[self setNeedsLayout]`**.
- In your initialisation method, create two image views, one holding your arrow (which should be the size of the arrow dimensions in your class methods) and one holding your background image (which must be a resizable image) and add these as subviews. It doesn't matter where you put the subviews at this point, as you don't have an arrow direction or offset. You should make sure the arrow image view is above the background image view so it blends in properly.
- Implement `layoutSubviews`. In here, according to the `arrowDirection` and `arrowOffset` properties, you have to adjust the frames of your background view and arrow view.

  - The frame of your background view should be `self.bounds`, inset by `arrowHeight` on whatever edge the arrow is on
  - The frame of the arrow view should be aligned so that the centre is `arrowOffset` away from the centre of `self` (correct according to the axis). You have to change the image orientation if the arrow direction is not up, but my popover would only be up so I didn't do that.

Here is the `layoutSubviews` method for my Up-only subclass:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (self.arrowDirection == UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp)
    {
        CGFloat height = [[self class] arrowHeight];
        CGFloat base = [[self class] arrowBase];

        self.background.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - height);

        self.arrow.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5 + self.arrowOffset - base * 0.5, 1.0, base, height);
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.arrow];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another link only answer, but customising `UIPopoverBackgroundView` is more work than you might realise given the limited documentation available and this github project has a complete working example which saved me a lot of time: https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView

It's fairly straightforward to drop into your own project. The most fiddly part is adapting the cap insets for whatever custom images you're using. I'd recommend doing your customisations in-situ in the project and as it's easy to verify all the popover orientation/direction use cases display correctly in the simulator before migrating it into your own project.