# In which case one should use Popover segue in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover, uipopover

I have few questions regarding Popover segue.

1) In what case one should use that?

2) In my case i have to show popover on button click and the popver having another view controller as shown in figure.1 [image: figure.1]

3) If one having image as popover then how to hide the outer native blue popover? as shown in figure.2 [image: figure.2]

4) What is the different in using Popover segue & using below code on button click

```
    classobj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:classobj];
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(689,10,50,50) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When you want to present a popover without having to write code as in example 4.

2) This is not a question

3) You can't simply drop in an image to use as a replacement for the popover's frame. You need to define a custom subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView, as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205846/using-uipopoverbackgroundview-class/12314596#12314596).

4) Your code has a set location and arrow direction, the segue will infer these for you based on the location in your VC. If you want further customisation, but still to use a segue, you can use `prepareForSegue:`.