# remove shadow caused by uipopover

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a button, when pressed a popover pop's up, dropping some shadow on the current view to show the popup effect, the way it is supposed to happen.
 I need when the button is pressed, not to show any drop shadow under it.
This is an image showing on the right the popover controller and on the left the shadow that needs to be removed. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Note that the popover takes place when this button is clicked and it will appear above the current view, putting the layer of unwanted shadow.

Comment: is that what you are talking about ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235236/how-to-remove-the-fuzzy-drop-shadow-in-the-uipopovercontroller

Comment: or else you can approach https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/index.html

Comment: @Suhaiyl i don't want to change anything inside the popover, my problem is when the popover shows up, it create a gray transparent layer underneath it and above the current view, this is what i want to remove